# What wold be a viable defense against hostile dragon armies?

Tags: magic, warfare, dragons, low-fantasy

As you may know, there are two types of dragons in my world: wyverns and noble dragons. Wyverns are essentially the classic dragon: smart as a dog, bulky, loves treasure, tamable if you're stubborn enough, and most importantly, solitary. Since armies in this world are quite well equipped, a hostile wyvern is not much of a threat. Sure, many lives will be lost, but it would be easily dispatched. Then there are noble dragons. Slim and lithe, but intelligent, being able to metalwork and use magic, as well as living in tribes. While most noble dragon tribes are friendly or indifferent, some are hostile. And let me ask you this: **How can an *almost* average renaissance-era army combat a small army of spellcasting, well armored dragon warriors?** Do note that there are spellcasters in the humanoid army, but since it's extremely expensive to train them, most can only cast simple spells. Also, I am currently ignoring magical materials.

BTW, here's a [link](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/121156/the-new-world-project) to my chatroom if you're interested in the world.

Comment: Numbers. And crossbows.

Comment: @workerjoe Elaborate.

Comment: I'm sure this kind of question has been done before.  Besides, it's your story!  You decide what you want to happen in it.

Comment: @workerjoe I'm just asking for strategies.

Comment: The more interesting question is what would be a viable defense against obnoxiously friendly dragon hoards that don't know the meaning of personal space?

Comment: Do your dragons fly?

Comment: You may be "asking for strategies," but you've given nothing for the community to work with. How many dragons are there? How many soldiers? What's the terrain like? Can the dragons fly? Can they burrow? Breathe fire? Do they have paper-like skin or heavy scales? What kind of magic do they use? Can they summon storms, throw fireballs, or heal wounds? (Note that the [tag:magic] tag specifically mentions you need to define your magic system.) There are too many unknowns for this question to be answerable in its current form.

Comment: @Willk Yes, although the big ones can only fly in certain areas. Don't ask, because it's complicated and I'm lazy.

Comment: @Frostfyre I haven't created a magic system yet, so for convenience, the D&D magic system will do. I will tell you when I have devised one.

Comment: I ask about flying because if you have air units that can participate in a battle that opens up strategic options.

Comment: @Willk Interesting. Perhaps tamed wyverns or friendly noble dragons? Actually, tamed wyverns are a lot more likely. Wind magic can also probably be put into play.

Comment: No matter how you look at it, something being "easily dispatched" usually isn't what you call a threat that commonly results in several casualties until it's dealt with. In addition: what magic exactly can they use (you only specified what kind in a comment, and dnd has a vast amount of spells that can be used in several different ways depending on what the DM deems acceptable) ? What does "well equipped" means for a dragon, and how hard is it to kill a completely unnequipped one? How many dragons will attack? What strategies do they normally use since they're intelligent?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pike and Shot

Luckily, an average Renaissance-era army has the essential ingredients to resist these dragons already. They will need lots of ranged weapons, as winged spellcasters (and possibly firebreathers?) would otherwise be able to strafe them with impunity from above. Muskets/arquebuses fill this role nicely, as their armour-piercing qualities will make them more dangerous to the dragons' scale-and-armour combo than bows would be. Musketeers on their own would be vulnerable to the dragons closing into melee range quickly by air, but you can protect them using pike formations which can present a wall of bristling points in any direction (crucially, including upwards) from which the dragon tries to approach. From the dragon's perspective, it's like fighting a giant hedgehog which spits bullets.

So your key tactical until is essentially something like a 16th-century infantry tercio, in which musketmen around the edges harass the enemy as he approaches before withdrawing to within the protection of a big central block of pikemen. The other main elements of a Renaissance-era army, cavalry and artillery, will be of less use to you. Cannon will be near-impossible to aim against a target that moves fast in three-dimensional space, and likewise the main advantage of horsemen - superior mobility - is negated by dragons' ability to simply take flight and avoid them (plus, it will be hard to make horses close with scary reptilian super-predators). I would perhaps give each army a few units of dragoons (mounted musket infantry) who can move quickly to reinforce any tercio which comes under concentrated attack from lots of dragons, but that's about it.

Strategy-wise, you will never be able to match the dragons for mobility, but if they apparently have farms, metalworking facilities, and other essential static infrastructure, you can send your forces to capture or destroy these. The dragons must either lose their logistical base or give battle, in which case your tercios will stand a fighting chance of defeating them.

Comment: Very good solution, and it doesn't even need magic!

Comment: Also, yes, my dragons do breath fire. And frost. And poison. And acid. And lightning. And sometimes lasers. Really, it depends on the species.

Answer (score 3):

**Guerilla Warfare**

Just like today when faced by a larger, more powerful, army, you hide and strike from concealment.

Dragons eat a lot of meat so someone slipping some poison in could kill a lot of dragons without the enemy seeing a single man. A match into the wheat crops could leave a lot of starving peasants.

There is much a few good men could do to cause chaos with virtually no risk to themselves.

Comment: Interesting concept. This would be even more effective on my dragons, since they are omnivorous and rely heavily on farming and ranching.

Answer (score 1):

As with any conflict, you need to know your enemy first.  Every little thing about them.  Everything you can find out.  I'm not saying a human could think like a flying reptilian super predator, but you should try.  Every scrape of information, no matter how trivial you might think at the time, is important.  You have to build your strategy on that information, and missing something may prove fatal.

Second, You need to know what your own goals are in a very clear way.  If you want something, you need to know what kind of price you are willing to pay for it.

Both of these are absolutely critical when contemplating going to war with any enemy, but especially when that enemy is as big, scary and powerful as a group of Dragons.

Next, you have to create a strategy for each of the Dragon's abilities based on what you have learned from them.  Flight?  How big of a net do you need to take them down?  Can you prevent them from taking off?  Claws?  what kind of armor can protect against that, or can we use the terrain to help by hiding in the trees to prevent a good swat?  Just methodically work each problem with a counter measure.  Look at the dragon's supply chain.    A human army marches on it's stomach.  A Dragon Army may fly on it's stomach.  Find out if they can take food with them and for how long.  you may find that an individual dragon can go a long way in a day, but may only be able to stay away from home for 2 days.  That will severely limit their range.  You may be able to build a very strong base just outside the dragon's home with impunity and then have a much easier time projecting later.

Then start combining that with all the stuff you thought might have been trivial.  Things like a winter torpor that might make dragons slower and easier to kill.  Maybe after a clutch of eggs is laid the females always stay with the eggs relying on the males for food.  That may create opportunities in that killing off a few males means there are fewer dragons in the next generation.  Or you might time a major assault as half the possible fighting force is locked down to one location.  Also keep in mind that you may want to pay attention to things like mothers getting uber protective of the young, so you keep back from nesting sites.  Every bit of information is important.  Nothing is too trivial.  Even something like a food preference can be used.  If they like beef, making sure a supply of tainted cows in the dragons hunting grounds could allow you to strike a massive blow without a single human soldier being at risk.

Finally, give some good hard thought into why you would fight the dragons.  If it is a matter of resources, you might find trade to be the far better method to deal with them.  You already have battle plans, just in case.  Taking a bit of time to negotiate costs almost nothing and may well gain a lot without massive loss of life.

Of course, if the dragons find human flesh tasty and want to just wipe us out or keep us as a food source, you won't be able to negotiate so you may as well start looking to time the attacks as soon as practical.

As a sort of appendix you may want to know some specific weapons.
Nets:  forget trying to throw or project them. that may only work if the dragons are coming in large, closely spaced groups. Use nets as traps or snares.
Projectile weapons:  try to figure out how to penetrate the scales with the lightest, fastest weapon possible.  one that you can very quickly change the point of aim.  Longbows, crossbows, arquebuses, and so on will be much more effective than heavy, difficult to aim pieces.
Magic:  focus first on countering the Dragon magic.  There is an old adage that it is much easier to break something than to build it.  Focus first on countering and you lower level mages will be more effective.
Tactics.  Stick to tree cover, canyons, anything that reduces one or more advantages a flying creature would have.  Tree limbs may make flight difficult.  Canyons may let you set up hidden snares and nets.  Dragon's head can't fit in a burrow or cave.  And so on.  Attack during a winters torpor.  Poisons during the mating season.  Withdraw while the dragons are active.

Comment: This makes me wish I can accept two answers. Very good.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know the broader thought on your world / realm but especially if this a matter of species for the humans, it's probably best to have them band together and create an alliance to bring to bear the abilities and capabilities of more than one kingdom, tribe, etc. How many (approx) are in this dragon army ? Weighted trebuchet launched nets, large crossbow harpoons, and trebuchet launched fuel / accelerant could easily be lit by simple fire spells of the low level casters or archers.